# Map creates only one li - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a component that creates Tabs when you click on an item in the navigation menu.
All the controls I do in the father to be able to pass the states between the brothers without problems.
As it is now my code when clicking on a menu item creates a unique `<li>` and shows the name. If you click on the entire menu item, it does not create a new `<li>`, but rather updates the old one with the new menu information.
I need that every time I press a menu item a new `<li>` with its content is created.

**I edit my code with @technogeek1995 changes and this the final solution:**

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);

        ["openTabs",].forEach((method) => {
            this[method] = this[method].bind(this);
        });

        this.state = {
            navigation: {
                menu: [],
            },
            tabs:{
                tabsLi:[],    
            },
            textvalue : "",
            showtabs: true,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('json_menu.php')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>{
                this.setState({navigation: data});
                //console.log(data)
            })
    }
    openTabs(e, url, iframe, trdtitle){
        e.preventDefault();
        const state = {...this.state};
        state.textvalue = trdtitle.split();
        state.tabs.tabsLi.push(state.textvalue);
        console.log(state.tabs.tabsLi)
        this.setState({ state });
        this.setState({ 
            showtabs: false,
        }); 
    }
```

```
class Tabs extends Component {
    render(){
        const renderTabs = tabs =>{
            return(
                <div id="content-tabs" className="tabs">
                {( this.props.showtabs)  
                    ? (
                        <>
                        <div className="waiting-leads">
                            <p>Parece que todavía no hay ningún lead...</p>
                            <h3>¡Ánimo, ya llega!</h3>
                            <img src={imgDinosaurio} alt="Dinosaurio"></img>
                        </div>
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <ul id="resizable" className="content" >
                            {this.props.tabs.tabsLi.map((value, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <li key={index}>
                                        <span>{value}</span>
                                        <Icon icon="cerrar" className='ico-cerrar' onClick={remove_tab(index)}/>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })}
                        </ul>
                )}
                </div>
            );
        }
        return (
            <>
                {renderTabs(this.props.tabs.tabsLi)}
            </>
            )
    }
}
```

This is the code that is generated when you click on the menu item. The `<span>` is the one that is updated and no new `<li>` is created. Ventas is my element menu name.

```
<ul id="resizable" class="content">
    <li>
        <span>Ventas</span>
        <svg class="ico-cerrar">path</svg>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you post your imports too ? thanks.

Comment: I edit my code with my imports @Legeo

Comment: Can you add your `App` component's render function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be related to mutating the state directly. You should see some warnings in the console/terminal about mutating react's state directly. I have updatd your `openTabs` function so that it no longer mutates the state directly. Instead, I copy state to a local variable, perform the mutations of the local state object. Then, I call `setState` with the locally updated state object. React will automatically pick up the changes to the state and render the page with the (newly) updated state.

```
openTabs(e, url, iframe, trdtitle){
        e.preventDefault();
        const state = {...this.state};
        state.textvalue = trdtitle.split();
        state.navigation.menu.push(state.textvalue);
        state.showtabs = false;
        this.setState({ state });
}
```

Tabs Component needed to be updated to iterate over the list, rather than over the string so it will create a `<li>` for every element in `state.navigation.menu`. `remove_tab` needed to be wrapped in `{}` instead of `""` as well.

```
class Tabs extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      div id = "content-tabs"
      className = "tabs" > {
        (this.props.showTabs) ? (
          <div className = "waiting-leads" >
            <p> Parece que todavía no hay ningún lead... </p>
            <h3> ¡Ánimo, ya llega! </h3>
            <img src={imgDinosaurio} alt="Dinosaurio"/>
          </div>
        ) : (
        <ul id = "resizable" className = "content" >
          {this.props.tabs.map((value, index) => (
                <li key={index} >
                  <span>{value}</span>
                  <Icon icon = "cerrar" className = 'ico-cerrar' onClick={remove_tab(index)} / >
                </li>
              )
          } </ul>
        )} </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are still mutating state.

Comment: Hi @technogeek1995. This code continues to do the same as my code and does not throw any errors into the console.

Comment: Good catch. I updated my answer so that I am not mutating state directly anymore. @JuniusL.

Comment: @ technogeek1995 Something strange happens. They create ``<li>`` but in another site of the page and not in my ``Tabs`` Component ``(this.props.textvalue)`` Do you know why?

Comment: What is rendering your `Tabs` component? My guess is that something is off with the passing of `props` to `Tabs`. In `Tabs`, you're mapping over `textvalue`, I think you want to map over `navigation.menu` since that's the array?

Comment: What I need is to show a ``<li>`` inside the ``<ul>`` in my ``Tabs`` component as in my original code that there is an example of what I need. In my original code when clicking, the ``<li>`` is painted, but only once, now it is painted in another place on the page

Comment: Should `state.showtabs` be set to `true` in `openTabs`?

Comment: showtabs is not related to that. It serves to show or not the tabs. If they do not show you put another image by default warning of the error. showtabs must be false for show a new tab

Comment: I updated the answer @Casandra. I still think the issue with the `<li>`'s is because you have to map over an array - and not the string, which is why you're only seeing 1 <li>. It also could be something with the key - I am using the value of the array here so it will work between renders. It's not great though as it's not globally unique. `remove_tab` needs to be in `{}` not quotes too.

Comment: If this doesn't solve it, it would make sense to mark this as resolved and open a new question for whatever isn't working now because it's not coming clear through the code of any potential issue. There's not enough information from the source code/description to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the callback version of state and use the spread syntax to create new objects with new references so that React detects the change in state.

`this.state.navigation.menu.push(this.state.textvalue)`
Also, this line will push the old `textValue` and not the new one which is `trdtitle.split()`

```
openTabs(e, url, iframe, trdtitle){
        e.preventDefault();
        const textValue = trdtitle.split()
        this.setState(state => ({
            textvalue,
            showtabs: false,
            navigation: { 
                ...state.navigation, 
                menu: [ ...state.navigation.menu, textValue ] 
            }
        })); 
    }
```